# Anaconda 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named cv2'

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda, spyder

I am currently trying to run code from the following GitHub repo on my computer:

https://github.com/andresberejnoi/ComputerVision

I have Anaconda3 installed and have used the prompt to create a virtual environment. However, no matter which commands I try, it flags an error at the line of code 'import cv2', saying the module cannot be found. I made sure the virtual environment is in the appropriate Python version, and I have tried:

conda install -c menpo opencv

conda install opencv

conda install opencv -c conda-forge

pip install opencv-python

pip3 install opencv-python

pip3 install opencv-contrib-python

I've tried these all in a fresh virtual environment, and none seems to be working. Does anyone know how to resolve this issue? Thanks!

PS: I don't know if this related to the issue, but whenever I try to activate a virtual environment in Spyder, I get a message saying 'Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.' However, this message persists after I restart the kernel, essentially meaning I can't use conda in Spyder. That's why I have been sticking to the Anaconda3 prompt instead.

Comment: You should not have multiple versions of OpenCV in the same environment. Just stick to one version. Create a new virtual environment and install using `pip install opencv-contrib-python`

Comment: Thank you for the response; I tried doing this, but am still getting the same error.

Comment: Since you are using a conda env you will need to set the custom interpreter preference pointing to the new env where you installed OpenCV and install also there the spyder-kernels package. For more info you can check the Spyder docs FAQ page: https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/faq.html#using-existing-environment . Another option is to install Spyder into the new env from conda-forge and launch Spyder from there